# Getting two same value when doing console.log(current)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I try console.log( current) I get two identical values simultaneously.
please find below the whole code

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const numberOfElements = Data.length;
      setCurrentIndex((prev) => {
        const current = (prev + 1) % numberOfElements;
        console.log(current);
        
        return current;
      });
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to reacts [strict mode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode), also check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNaPTkadnao)

ps. don't disable strict mode as it will potentially introduce stupid bugs in your code